# Check is page is visited (through anchor tag) by only allowed websites

Tags: php, redirect, http-referer

Lets say I have a website abc.com/redirect.php which has an anchor tag which links blank to xyz.com/landing.php.

I want to check if the xyz.com/landing.php is opened only through abc.com/redirect.php .

Get parameters are not allowed as someone may copy it on their website. HTTP referer header is not reliable and is not working in this case.

Comment: Well you won’t be able to do this without passing _any_ information along between the two pages. _“as someone may copy it on their website”_ - then try and make that harder, for example by creating a token with a limited validity. Or have abc.com make an AJAX request to xyz.com in the background first, that sets some cookie or session entry on xyz.com. (Other pages won’t be able to easily fake that from the client side, if you check the request `Origin` properly.)

Comment: 2 down votes, but why?

Comment: For asking a question, that is basically anything else but new. For not showing any effort on your end, other than telling us what you _can’t_ use. Your question is basically the typical “me want, you make”.

Comment: borther I come to stackoverflow only after trying my best.

Answer (score -2):

You can use cookie or session.
Example via cookie

```php
<?php
// redirect.php
if(isset($_COOKIE['visited'])) {
    header('Location: xyz.com/landing.php');
}
setcookie('visited', '1');
?>
```

Example via sesion:

```php
<?php
// redirect.php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['visited'])) {
    header('Location: xyz.com/landing.php');
}
$_SESSION['visited'] = 1;
?>
```

For checking referrer on xyz.com/landing.php you can use global `$_SERVER` variable. For example:

```php
<?php
// landing.php
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == "http://example.com/redirect.php") {
    // do something
}
?>
```

Comment: How would a cookie or session on the _originating_ end help?

Comment: set cookie/session variable and check this, if that setted - do redirect. If need make "multi domain cookie" please, look to 5-th argument https://www.php.net/set_cookie

Comment: The question is not about preventing the redirect, the question is about _any other site_ on the net being able to redirect or link to `xyz.com/landing.php` itself directly.

Comment: We cannot set cookies for other websites, the same for the session.

Comment: OK, for cross domain session isn't working, yes, that's my miss understand. Why cookie isn't working in this case? I can set cookie from `domain1.com` for `domain1.com` and `domain2.com`

Comment: You can only set a cookie for domain2.com, when the browser makes an actual request for domain2.com. As I mentioned in the comments above already, an AJAX request made from the first domain would be an option to do that. (That cookie might still get _blocked_ by privacy settings though, for being a 3rd-party cookie in this scenario. So depending on what level of “reliability” in terms of it actually working in the wild is needed, that might not be enough.)